# How to return a value from one script to another in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, return-value

Script2

```
def timer():
    time.sleep(10)
    return True

retvalue = timer()
```

=========================================================================
Script 1

```
retvalue = subprocess.call(['python', 'Script2.py'])
print(retvalue)
```

I have also tried returning an integer but retvalue remains 0 in Script 1

Comment: You basically don't. You can serialize an object and transmit it through a pipe. Printing it to stdout and reading in on the other side is one form of doing that.

Comment: What's the point of returning a value that's always True? And why are you using subprocess to run that function instead of importing it and calling it normally?

Comment: I am trying to run a second script along with the first that I can execute and have return a value when it is finished so that the first script isn't 'hung' on waiting for the code to finish. I would then try to use threading to check the value and keep the main program running. I was having problems using threading with the functions in my main program because they are triggered by events so I was trying to find a workaround.

Comment: In that case, you should post a more realistic example, preferably a [mcve] so we can help you to get the threading to work correctly. But anyway, in Script2 you can do `sys.exit(retval)` to return a numeric exit code. But that's a really clunky way to do stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I will do that with the next post.

Answer (score 0):

retvalue is receiving the exit code from the `subprocess.call()`.  The value "0" is for the successful completion of the command that you spawned.

In your example, nothing from Script2 is returning to Script1

Script2 should be imported and then its functions can be called.

Script1.py

```
import Script2
retvalue = Script2.timer()
```

note:  you should add the boilerplate code in Script2 so you're not executing Script2.py when importing

Comment: I had no idea it was getting an exit code, but that makes sense. Thank you cortruu